# Deadlock on same table with UPDATE-OUTPUT transaction

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2, deadlock

I found a bunch of deadlock error events on my log.

The transaction that caused the deadlock was an Update-Output transaction (eg. Update table1 ... Output table1.some_id... which I think is basically the same as an Update-Select transaction. I wasn't able to check if the transactions are accessing the same row because the log only showed the variables used.

From the Deadlock graph generated from the trace, it seems that they're using the same table and non-clustered index. On the Index's property, row lock and page lock is checked. Any way how to prevent this from happening again? or steps to help me diagnose further?

Comment: post the deadlock graph (the XML, not the picture of it...)

Comment: What about the second statement in the deadlock?

Comment: all three statements are the same UPDATE-OUTPUT transactions. is there a way to prevent access while one transaction is running at a time? row lock and page lock is checked on the index's properties.